# How to resolve uncaught promise error in odoo15?

Tags: odoo-15

In Odoo 15, I can not open settings app for it throws error given below:

Uncaught Promise > Couldn't load css dependency: http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/assets/425-d7a4117/web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.min.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved after installing pip3 install libsass==0.17.0

Comment: You saved my day, worked on odoo 15. THank you

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to use debug mode > bug icon > regenerate asset bundles